# filter php array by value using array_filter

Tags: php

I am trying to filter an array which will produce a drill down list.
This array is built from JSON.

My array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [make] => somemake
            [model] => somemodel
            [variant] => somevariant
            [fuel] => somefuel
            [vehicle] => somedetailedinfo
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [make] => somemake
            [model] => somemodel1
            [variant] => somevariant1
            [fuel] => somefuel1
            [vehicle] => somedetailedinfo
        )
     [2] => Array
        (
            [make] => somemake
            [model] => somemodel2
            [variant] => somevariant2
            [fuel] => somefuel
            [vehicle] => somedetailedinfo
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [make] => somemake1
            [model] => somemodel3
            [variant] => somevariant3
            [fuel] => somefuel1
            [vehicle] => somedetailedinfo
        )

)
```

I would like to filter this array by the make `$make`, which is set by the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

The new array should contain all items with the make `$make`.

How do I do this using `array_filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straight-forward. Note that null coalesce (`??`) is >= 7.0.

```
$make = $_GET['make'] ?? 'Chevy';
$vehicles = [[
    'make' => 'Ford',
    'model' => 'F-150',
    'variant' => '4x4',
    'fuel' => 'diesel',
    'vehicle' => [range(1,3)],
],[
    'make' => 'Ford',
    'model' => 'Escort',
    'variant' => 'XS',
    'fuel' => 'gas',
    'vehicle' => [range(1,3)],
],[
    'make' => 'Chevy',
    'model' => 'Cobalt',
    'variant' => 'ES',
    'fuel' => 'electric',
    'vehicle' => [range(1,3)],
],[
    'make' => 'Ford',
    'model' => 'Explorer',
    'variant' => '2x4',
    'fuel' => 'gas',
    'vehicle' => [range(1,3)],
],[
    'make' => 'Mini',
    'model' => 'Cooper',
    'variant' => 'eTurbo',
    'fuel' => 'electro-diesel',
    'vehicle' => [range(1,3)],
],];

print_r(array_filter($vehicles, function($vehicle) use($make) {
    return $vehicle['make'] === $make;
}));
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [make] => Chevy
            [model] => Cobalt
            [variant] => ES
            [fuel] => electric
            [vehicle] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                            [2] => 3
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

https://3v4l.org/B8T6v